# How to convert text into a dataframe in Python (with applying some rules)

Tags: python, nlp

I am new to Python and have this complex function that I need to build but do not know how

I have a dataframe of text

```
RepID     RepText
---------------------------
1         Math Math Math  English Physics Sport Sport English English English English 
2         Sport English English English Math Math Physics Physics Physics Computer Computer Computer Computer 
3         Chemistry Chemistry Math Math Math English English English Math Math Math Math Math Sport Sport
```

The function I need to create called fnClusters

It just finds the N repeated words in the RepText and return them in a dataframe

if N is 3 then same words that showed 3 times or more next to each other will be counted

so Math Math Math English Physics English English Math will count as

```
Math  English  Physics
------------------------
4       0       0
```

English English English English English Math Math Math English Math Sports Sports will count as

```
Math  English  Sports
------------------------
4       6       0
```

How can I build this function in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.split` with `value_counts`:

```
new_df = df["RepText"].str.split("\s+").apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
n = 3
print(new_df[new_df.ge(n)].fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
   English  Math  Sport  Physics  Computer  Chemistry
0      5.0   3.0    0.0      0.0       0.0        0.0
1      3.0   0.0    0.0      3.0       4.0        0.0
2      3.0   8.0    0.0      0.0       0.0        0.0
```

Comment: I get that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.Series'